# URLRequest to nginx server crashes

Tags: actionscript, nginx

The same code was working fine on lighttpd and apache, recently I switched to nginx and the app started crashing when I run it locally. However it runs fine with the same code inside a browser.
Here is the source code that makes a request to the server.

```
public function ApiCall(methodName:String,params:Object=null) 
{
        super();

        url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();


        variables.call = methodName;

        variables.params = JSON.encode(params);

        url.data = variables;

        this.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

        this.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        this.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
}

public function post():void
{
        try
        {
            this.load(url);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error Message : " + e.message);
        }

        // debug
        trace(url.data.call + " Params : " + url.data.params);
}
```

The flash player just crashes without any meaningfull error message.

I checked on the php side and the $_POST array is empty for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the URL used to make the http request, I was using http://www.domain.com in the as3 code, the domain and the rewrite rules were http://domain.com, this somehow broke the request.

Removing the www from the url in AS3 fixed the problem.

Comment: +1 I'm sure this happens to a lot of people - good question/answer.